# Error "Failed to load PDF document" when i access link file pdf on magento 2

Tags: magento2

Locally it works fine but on production it gives this error.

I uploaded the file in the Downloadable Information section of the product
All other files work normally, but only the pdf file has this error.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZYQ2.png)

How does it work?